# how to copy a row from a datagridview to another datagridview when cell value change

Tags: c#

When I make a change in my first datagridview1 data then I want to copy, then I want to copy only the changed row data from datagridview1 to datagridview2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        string query = @"Select Item.ItemName as item, Stock.SalePrice as 
        Price, invoice.Qty 
        FROM invoice
        JOIN item ON invoice.ItemID = item.ItemID
        JOIN sale ON invoice.SaleID = sale.SaleID
        join Stock on Stock.ItemID  = item.ItemID 
        where sale.SaleID = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
        btn.HeaderText = "Update";
        btn.Text = "Update";
        btn.Name = "btnUpdate";
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
}
```

I call the cell value change event, but the code to copy only edited rows.

please provide me code:

Comment: I wouldn't use words "please provide me code" when asking someone to help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `CellValueChanged` event of `datagGridview1`,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
    {
        dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow modifiedRow = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            if (dataGridView2.DataSource != null)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource;
                //"Id" is name of the column that has unique, non-nullable values
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(x => x["Id"].ToString() == modifiedRow["Id"].ToString()) != null)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(x => x["Id"].ToString() == modifiedRow["Id"].ToString()).ToList()[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(modifiedRow);
        }
    }
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Hope this helps...